WPF - Styling the progress bar removes it's cycling abilities
As I try to change the progress bar colors, it now displays the background color when progress bar is in cycle mode
an image of the applied style will be better than any explanation

as I apply this style, the progress bar does not cycle anymore, it is filled with the same color
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
                <Grid x:Name="TemplateRoot" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <Rectangle x:Name="PART_Track" 
                               Fill="{DynamicResource MyDimmedBrush}" />
                    <Rectangle x:Name="PART_Indicator"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                               Fill="{DynamicResource MyBrush}"
                               Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

thanks for your help

What you call cycle mode is the indeterminate state of the ProgressBar, set by the IsIndeterminate property. The ControlTemplate in your Style is apparently missing a visualization of that state. See the ProgressBar Styles and Templates for an example.

thanks for your help, I just had to override the colors

Apparently it is as simple as this
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="blue" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="red" />
</Style>

